# Python: Tests and Setup do not get run

Tags: python

Both the setup and the test method do not seem to run when i execute the below code. Can anyone advise why this must be?

```
class InstallTest():
    """Ru Ovirt System Tests"""

    def setUp(self):
        """Test Case Setup"""
        Log.test_objective('Hi!!!')
        self.client = Client(OSSE_OLV_TESTBOX_HOST, OSSE_OLV_TESTBOX_USER,
                             OSSE_OLV_TESTBOX_PASS)
        self.client.concurrency = OSSE_OLV_TESTBOX_CONCURRENCY

        self.log_jobdir = os.getenv('osse_log_jobdir')
        self.log_jobdir_cc = os.path.join(self.log_jobdir, 'config_collect')

        LOG.Log.test_setup('Instantiate Client object')
        self.client_mgmt = _list(OSSE_OFSS_CLIENT_MGMT)
        self.client_head_list = str(OSSE_OFSS_CLIENT_HEAD_LIST)
        if self.client_head_list == '-1':
            self.client_head_list = 0
        self.head = self.client_mgmt[int(self.client_head_list)]
        self.client = CLIENT.Client(self.head,
                                    OSSE_OFSS_CLIENT_USER,
                                    OSSE_OFSS_CLIENT_PASS)

        self.client_luniqname = str(OSSE_OFSS_LUN_UNIQNAME)
        self.vdbench_binary = str(OSSE_OFSS_VDBENCH_BINARY_PATH) + '/vdbench'
        self.vdbench_out_path = str(OSSE_OFSS_VDBENCH_OUT_PATH) + '/'
        template = str(OSSE_OFSS_VDBENCH_TEMPLATE_FILE)
        if template.startswith('/'):
            self.vdbench_template = template
        else:
            self.vdbench_template = \
                os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/' + template

        self.host = self.client.hostname_get()
        msg = 'Setup the {0} client'.format(self.host)
        LOG.Log.test_setup(msg)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.client.close()

    def test_install_lago(self):        
        assert (1 == 1)
```

The last assert is just put in as filler for now in case assert is necessary for test methods

Comment: How are you executing it?

Answer (score 3):

Your class doesn't inherit a test case.

```
import unittest
class InstallTest(unittest.TestCase):
```

Answer (score 1):

First, as already answsered by Sayse, your class needs to inherit from `unittest.TestCase`. Also, unless this code is built on some frameworks that already includes it's own testrunners (ie Django 'manage.py test'), you need to actually execute the TestCase test methods:

```
import unittest

class YourTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
   # ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Note that [all this is documented...](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example)